# failed to send a get request using fetch api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch some data from the server and I am using **react.js**
and the fetch api but a get that

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`
this is my code for fetching the data

```
componentDidMount() {
    // fetch all categories from the server
    fetch('http:localhost:5555/categories')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(categories => {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
            console.log(categories);
            this.setState({ categories });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

any thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your fetch method and you write the **url** in the wrong form 
try to change the url from

```
http:localhost:5555/categories
```

to

```
http://localhost:5555/categories
```

any try to fetch again